# OpenGraph tags are ignored

Tags: facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph

For whatever reason, the facebook is not reading the opengrapgh tags on the following pages:

http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/court-order-city-t-occupy-wall-street-protesters-stuff-zuccotti-park-article-1.977674

The FB Linter passes w/o any issues:

```
{
   "url": "http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/court-order-city-t-occupy-wall-street-protesters-stuff-zuccotti-park-article-1.977674",
   "type": "article",
   "title": "Court order: City can\u2019t keep Occupy Wall Street\u00a0protesters and their stuff out of Zuccotti Park \u00a0",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.977661!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/searchthumbnail_75/image.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "description": "Hours after baton-wielding cops cleared Occupy Wall Street protesters and their tents out of Zuccotti Park, a judge signed a order Tuesday saying the demonstrators can return with their stuff.",
   "site_name": "NY Daily News",
   "updated_time": "2011-11-15T14:48:15+0000",
   "id": "10150378344639794"
}
```

However when I try to like/recommend, only the link is pulled on my wall, and not any other tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare [your given url](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/judge-rules-city-bar-occupy-wall-street-tents-tarps-zuccotti-park-evictions-article-1.977674/) with [another article's url](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.nydailynews.com/news/national/9-year-old-girl-survives-days-trapped-overturned-car-crash-article-1.977728) You'll notice an extra section in your URL's version .... "Redirect Path" ... with the HTTP Code 301 which indicates an Permanent Redirect ... seems like this page is being redirected behind the scenes ... Hopefully that sheds some light on the issue ...

Little more info on the [HTTP 301 Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)